# Python-Mysql REGEXP with variable

Tags: python, mysql, regex

I can do a regular variable substitution in mysql/python using:

```
    cursor.execute("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`item_start`,'%%Y-%%m') AS ym,
                           count(*) as num
                      from t_calendar_data
                      where Concat(item_subject, ' ', item_text_body) like %s
                      group by ym",
             ("%{}%".format(i),))
```

but I'm not sure how to use REGEXP with:

```
    [[:<:]]VARIABLE[[:>:]]
```

I've tried various forms of:

```
    cursor.execute("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`item_start`,'%%Y-%%m') AS ym, 
    count(*) as num from t_calendar_data where Concat(item_subject, ' ', 
    item_text_body) REGEXP %s group by ym", ("[[:<:]]%{}%
    [[:>:]]".format(i),))
```

with no success. How do I wrap the regex (assuming I'm putting REGEXP in the correct spot)?

Comment: `"[[:<:]]{}[[:>:]]".format(i)`

Answer (score 0):

Wiktor's response worked perfect.  I had to remove my extra %.